# Access Android file system through ubuntu 14.04 over LAN

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, linux, file-system

I have SOC which run android 4.4. I have connect this to my network using LAN. 
Now I want to access android root file using my Ubuntu desktop. Something like ssh. How to do this?

Comment: @Firelord I am new in android world ...so I have tried from file explorer and I have dual boot of android and Ubuntu so tried to see android file system from Ubuntu...but not having success. I thought do it without  install any app. is it possible? llike ssh (we use between target and host Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Droid VNC Server**

Allows you to remote control your android within your computer.

**Note:Your phone must be ROOTED!**

**Note:Will not work on Tegra3 Devices**
On your android Phone:

- Install Droid VNC Server from playstore.
- Open the app and click on START.
- It shows the ip-address and port number.Please note it down.

On your Ubuntu PC:

Install xtightvncviewer by running the below command,

```
sudo apt-get install xtightvncviewer
```

After installing xtightvncviewer run the below command to view your phone's screen,

```
vncviewer xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
```

xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx - is already noted ipaddress:port

---

Or Use

### **WebKey**

Using this application you can control your phone from any browser.

Note:Your phone must be ROOTED!
On your android Phone:

- Install WebKey app from playstore.
- Open the app and select start service.
- Note down the https link generated.

On that same application,go to settings->User settings->Click on Create new user to create a new user with login credentials.
**On your Ubuntu PC:**

- Open any browser.I prefer firefox.Then paste the noted link on the
  address bar.It display like connection is not secure.Trust the
  connection and allow it to load.
- After that a page will open and ask you to give the username and
  password.Login with the same username and password.
- After loged into your account,you can view your phone and operate
  your android phone from there.

  ---

  Or Use

### **Team Viewer**

Note: It will work on most devices

- Install teamviewer on both Ubuntu PC and android phone to control
  your phone from PC.
  Hope it helps:).